# Google's GeoChart wont display Cork within Ireland map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, charts, google-visualization

I'm drawing a province map for Ireland and for some reason Google's doesn't recognise county Cork. Someone suggested using IE-CO. But that breaks my plans on using a CSV dataset(where I have no control over county names).

Does anyone know why it doesn't work and how can I fix that?

Here a sample of my code https://jsfiddle.net/sashareds/kLjtne42/2/

```
 google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages':['geochart'],
        // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
        // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
        'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyBgxLAOHUq52CuZ0kcl9WHnOjzt40w082k'
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['County',   'Case'],
        ['Carlow',   0],
        ['Cavan',   41],
        ['Clare',   50],
        ['Cork',   292], //IE-CO
        ['Donegal',   77],
        ['Dublin',   2077],
        ['Galway',   98],
        ['Kerry',   79],
        ['Kildare',   103],
        ['Kilkenny',   47],
        ['Laois',   16],
        ['Leitrim',   12],
        ['Limerick',   96],
        ['Longford',   16],
        ['Louth',   54],
        ['Mayo',   55],
        ['Meath',   88],
        ['Monaghan',   17],
        ['Offaly',   47],
        ['Roscommon',   13],
        ['Sligo',   26],
        ['Tipperary',   94],
        ['Waterford',   43],
        ['Westmeath',   86],
        ['Wexford',   18],
        ['Wicklow',   105]
        ]);

        var options = {
          region: 'IE', // Africa
          resolution: 'provinces',
          colorAxis: {colors: ['#f9cb9c', '#f07b50', '#ea4435']},
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          datalessRegionColor: '#fefefe',
          defaultColor: '#fefefe',
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      };
```

Comment: Seems like a data problem, not sure where to report that for the charts API

Comment: Google Charts support page links to [this GitHub page](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues).

Comment: created an issue there  https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2811

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a data view with a calculated column to replace the known problem countries.
and use object notation to allow the actual country name to show thru on the tooltip.

```
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([{
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var country = dt.getValue(row, 0);
      switch (country) {
        case 'Cork':
          country = {v: 'IE-CO', f: country};
          break;
      }
      return country;
    },
    label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
    type: data.getColumnType(0)
  }, 1]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages':['geochart'],
  // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
  // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
  'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyBgxLAOHUq52CuZ0kcl9WHnOjzt40w082k'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['County',   'Case'],
    ['Carlow',   0],
    ['Cavan',   41],
    ['Clare',   50],
    ['Cork',   292], //IE-CO
    ['Donegal',   77],
    ['Dublin',   2077],
    ['Galway',   98],
    ['Kerry',   79],
    ['Kildare',   103],
    ['Kilkenny',   47],
    ['Laois',   16],
    ['Leitrim',   12],
    ['Limerick',   96],
    ['Longford',   16],
    ['Louth',   54],
    ['Mayo',   55],
    ['Meath',   88],
    ['Monaghan',   17],
    ['Offaly',   47],
    ['Roscommon',   13],
    ['Sligo',   26],
    ['Tipperary',   94],
    ['Waterford',   43],
    ['Westmeath',   86],
    ['Wexford',   18],
    ['Wicklow',   105]
  ]);
  
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([{
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var country = dt.getValue(row, 0);
      switch (country) {
        case 'Cork':
          country = {v: 'IE-CO', f: country};
          break;
      }
      return country;
    },
    label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
    type: data.getColumnType(0)
  }, 1]);

  var options = {
    region: 'IE', // Africa
    resolution: 'provinces',
    colorAxis: {colors: ['#f9cb9c', '#f07b50', '#ea4435']},
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    datalessRegionColor: '#fefefe',
    defaultColor: '#fefefe',
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('geochart-colors'));
  chart.draw(view, options);  // <-- draw chart with data view
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="geochart-colors" style="width: 90%; height: 90%;"></div>
```

**EDIT**

when using a sheet for the data source,
the view needs to be created with the data table from the sheet.

so the view definition should be created,
after the data table is received.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['geochart'],
  'mapsApiKey': chartSettings.mapsApyKey
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

//querying external data from a spreadsheet.
function drawRegionsMap() {

  var queryString = encodeURIComponent('Select *');

  var queryData = new google.visualization.Query(chartSettings.mapDataSource + queryString);

  queryData.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();
  
 //Swapping IE-CO on COrk in the dta array, I assume?
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([{
    calc: function(dt, row) {
      var country = dt.getValue(row, 0);
      switch (country) {
        case 'Cork':
          country = {
            v: 'IE-CO',
            f: country
          };
          break;
      }
      return country;
    },
    label: 'Country',
    type: 'string'
  }, 1]);


  var options = {
    region: 'IE',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    colorAxis: {
      colors: ['#f9cb9c', '#f07b50', '#ea4435']
    },
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    datalessRegionColor: '#fefefe',
    defaultColor: '#fefefe',
  };


  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('map'));
  chart.draw(view, options);

}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var chartSettings = {

        mapsApyKey: "AIzaSyBgxLAOHUq52CuZ0kcl9WHnOjzt40w082k",
        mapDataSource: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YV7VSsG_nQXmL_L44cJSz4GrxOLIBNJrgd8qPXM_NQ0/gviz/tq?gid=249758876&headers=1&range=M21:N47&tq="

      };

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's a neat workaround! Thank you. I do wish it was just a silly mistake and I could solve it without added workarounds. Do you know if it's a bug and if it's easy to fix?

Comment: don't think it is anything we could fix, the api would need to correct...

Comment: Hey, would that work if I pull data from a spreadsheet with var query = new google.visualization.Query(URL); ?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but maybe you have a working example of how to pull data from spreadsheet? google's documentation isn't helpful enough

Comment: Alright, I made GeoChart code working with my spreadsheet, but I'm not if your code works. Could you please check https://jsfiddle.net/sashareds/8jdqer71/4/

Comment: please access the base url https://jsfiddle.net/sashareds/8jdqer71/

Comment: Can't figure out why chart.draw() can't pick up your part of the code

Comment: So, I see you use ```DataView(data);``` I thought at first data was just a variable to contain data source. but it looks like it's a reserved function or something?

Comment: Could you also elaborate a little bit on labels? Don't understand fully what is going on in there

Comment: Apart from that, thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: here --> `DataView(data);` -- I'm creating a data view, which is based on a data table. in this case, the data table `data` is what we receive from the spreadsheet. data views allow us to use calculated columns. the calculated column has three properties, (1) the calc function, which is the value of the column. we're using the same value from the data table, unless it is cork, where we replace the value. , (2) the column label, and (3) the column's data type -- hope this helps, didn't really follow your question...